# Haskell + division

Tags: haskell, arithmetic-expressions

Im able to sum the zth element of all of the tuples but for some weird reason I only get 1 after dividing my result by 2.

```
averageYear :: [(String, String, Int)] -> Int
averageYear [] = 0
averageYear ((x,y,z):xs) = (z + (averageYear xs)) `div` (length xs)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: lol sorry, huge brainfart

Answer (score 6):

The math is completely wrong.

```
averageYear [(_, _, 2010)] = (2010 + averageYear []) `div` 2
                           = (2010 + 0) `div` 2
                           = 2010 `div` 2
                           = 1005
```

To compute the average, you have to divide the sum by the number of items.

```
average :: [Int] -> Int
average xs = sum xs `div` length xs

averageYear :: [(String, String, Int)] -> Int
averageYear = average . map (\(_, _, year) -> year)
```

Comment: great solution.. could you clarify what the full stop does ( . ) and what the slash does in the last line? ty

Comment: In Haskell, `(.)` is the function composition operator, and `\x -> y` is a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

@Dietrich Epp 
 Length xs is zero and not two in your example.

```
   averageYear ((x,y,z):xs) = (z + (averageYear xs)) `div` (length xs)
```

If xs is empty then length xs equal zero and you divide by zero.